Via Python dataframe, how to create a list of numbers between 2 values
In a python dataframe, I have a result set like this - How do I extract all values between the min and max where the flag is 1?  Looking to use the result set as filters for another query.

Result set would be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25

Could you explain, why 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25
and not 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, 14, 15, 16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25

Your output should probably include values 14 & 15 (based on your description).
For the data shown there are no "overlaps". However, in case there are, you would probaby want to use a set to build your values.
Something like this:
from pandas import DataFrame

d: dict[str, list[int]] = {
    "FLAG": [1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
    "MIN": [1, 10, 12, 14, 16],
    "MAX": [9, 11, 13, 15, 25],
}
df: DataFrame = DataFrame(d)
result: set[int] = set()
for _, row in df[df["FLAG"] == 1].iterrows():
    _range = range(row["MIN"], row["MAX"] + 1)
    result.update(_range)
print(sorted(result))

Output:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]


This works, thank you!  How can I modify this to pull in an additional field?  Say the flag is not always 1 - How can I pull in the same flag for corresponding min and max values?

I am assuming that it is just a typo in your expected result, which is missing 14 & 15, if so here is an answer.
For this, the easiest way I could think of to convert from a DataFrame to a sequential list is to use the iterrows method to loop over the flagged rows and then append the ranges between the rows MIN and MAX together.
For the appending used here, you can see this answer for a more detailed explanation of how that works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/953097/12766634.
import pandas as pd
import itertools

df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    "FLAG":[1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
    "MIN": [1,10,12,14,16],
    "MAX": [9,11,13,15,25]})

flagged_rows = df[df["FLAG"] == 1]
sequence_list = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(
    range(_row["MIN"], _row["MAX"] + 1) for _, _row in flagged_rows[["MIN", "MAX"]].iterrows()))

